# wxWidgets and WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: windows, wxwidgets, title, move, drag

I am using wxWidgets with Visual C++ 2010.
One of my goals is being able to move a frame I created with any part of the window (client or otherwise). For this purpose, I have used WM_NCHITTEST in the past to fool Windows into thinking every part of my window is the title bar.
How should that be done in wxWidgets?

Answer (score 3):

After extensive research, due to inactivity on the answering department, I've found a somewhat acceptable (although not portable) solution:

```
WXLRESULT [your-wxWindow-inheriting-objectname-here]::MSWWindowProc(WXUINT message,WXWPARAM wParam,WXLPARAM
lParam)  
{  
    if(message==WM_NCHITTEST) { return HTCAPTION; }

    return wxFrame::MSWWindowProc(message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

This can be used for any WINAPI message.

Answer (score 0):

another portable solution maybe like this:

```
//assume your frame named wxUITestFrame
//headers
class wxUITestFrame : public wxFrame
{
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()

protected:
    void OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnLeftMouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnLeftMouseUp(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnMouseLeave(wxMouseEvent& event);

private:
    bool        m_isTitleClicked;
    wxPoint     m_mousePosition; //mouse position when title clicked
};


//cpp
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(wxUITestFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MOTION(wxUITestFrame::OnMouseMove)
    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(wxUITestFrame::OnLeftMouseDown)
    EVT_LEFT_UP(wxUITestFrame::OnLeftMouseUp)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(wxUITestFrame::OnMouseLeave)
END_EVENT_TABLE()


void wxUITestFrame::OnMouseMove( wxMouseEvent& event )
{
    if (event.Dragging())
    {
        if (m_isTitleClicked)
        {
            int x, y;
            GetPosition(&x, &y); //old window position

            int mx, my;
            event.GetPosition(&mx, &my); //new mouse position

            int dx, dy; //changed mouse position
            dx = mx - m_mousePosition.x;
            dy = my - m_mousePosition.y;

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            Move(x, y); //move window to new position
        }
    }
}

void wxUITestFrame::OnLeftMouseDown( wxMouseEvent& event )
{
    if (event.GetY() <= 40) //40 is the height you want to set for title bar
    {
        m_isTitleClicked = true;
        m_mousePosition.x = event.GetX();
        m_mousePosition.y = event.GetY();
    }
}

void wxUITestFrame::OnLeftMouseUp( wxMouseEvent& event )
{
    if (m_isTitleClicked)
    {
        m_isTitleClicked = false; 
    }
}

void wxUITestFrame::OnMouseLeave( wxMouseEvent& event )
{
    //if mouse dragging too fase, we will not get mouse move event 
    //instead of mouse leave event here.
    if (m_isTitleClicked)
    {
        int x, y;
        GetPosition(&x, &y);

        int mx, my;
        event.GetPosition(&mx, &my);

        int dx, dy;
        dx = mx - m_mousePosition.x;
        dy = my - m_mousePosition.y;

        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        Move(x, y);
    }
}
```

Actually, the solution mentioned by John Locke at 1st Floor is `more` suggested in wxMSW， and in linux like system we can simulate ALT BUTTON DOWN message when title is clicked.